# isset won't identify parameters in url

Tags: php, post, isset

I have the following code in my file.php file:

```
if (isset($_POST["activate"])){
    $confirmed = true;  
    $result = execute_query("UPDATE tributes SET t_confirm = 1 WHERE t_id=".$_POST["tid"]." AND t_activation='".$_POST["activate"]."'");
    if($result){

    }   
}else{
    print "NO"; 
}
```

I call this file throught he following url:

```
http://localhost/ccmta/tribute.php?tid=55&activate=QiScE8W76whfQD0Twd15enG31yDEf1iVGLL0SHEB9doqI16bd8kskOPXu6bGZE65o7XPp9EXUBCJS7IbcjNZ98hA8vR11b0Ve0Qm
```

but the isset function won't recognize the activate variable that's in parameter in the URL and falls into the else bracket. I've also called print_r to see what is in the $_POST variable and it's an empty array. Any idea why?

Comment: OK, nobody said it so I will. Using Request data directly in your query is a huge security hole. http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I've heard that too. For now I've exclusively used $_POST and $_GET (although incorrectly). Wouldn't these two data points accomplish the same tasks as $_REQUEST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - `$_POST` is the array of POST, not GET (query string/URL) data. If you want both, use `$_REQUEST`, otherwise, use `$_GET`.

Comment: Yup fixed it. So simple i overlooked it :/